# How do I use nth correctly here?

Tags: clojure

I'm pretty new to this, so I apologize if this seems trivial.

When trying to use nth, I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because the size of `lst` could be less than 2. How can I fix this?

```
(defn invert-helper [lst]
     (list (nth lst 1) (first lst)))
```

thanks!

Comment: Use `if` to test the length first.

Comment: Gah! I tried it earlier and I must've screwed up my if statement. Worked this time though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can also use `second`, it returns nil if `lst` is empty or nil. Of course you'd have to check for nil or empty sequence if that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `nth` function has a 3-arity option for the case where you don't want an exception thrown for being out of bounds. You provide, as the 3rd argument, the value you want returned in case the index is out of bounds. This avoids the inefficiency of first checking for the length and then doing `nth` in uncounted sequences.

```
user=> (nth [1 2 3] 5 nil)
nil

user=> (nth [1 2 3] 5 ::not-found)
:user/not-found
```